# Temperature of planets without atmosphere

Tags: thermodynamics, atmospheric-science, planets, thermal-radiation, vacuum

I am wondering how come a planet without atmoshhere loses heat in space when the space around it is a vacuum. In my understanding for one object to lose heat it must have contact with another object/particles around it so the particles can absord the heat energy from the object (correct me if I'm wrong about this).

Comment: I correct you. You are wrong. There are three ways to lose heat. Conduction - being in contact with something else; convection - having a fluid carry the heat to higher gravitational potential and then cool off; and radiation - energy is released in the form of EM radiation that is emitted in a way dependant on the object's temperature.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation

Comment: If planets could only lose heat through conduction, then a planet with an atmosphere would also not be able to lose heat to the vacuum of space.

Comment: Otherwise, one might also ask how a planet *with* an atmosphere cool off in space. It may have an atmosphere but outside the atmosphere is a vacuum. Planets with and without an atmosphere both lose heat via radiation. It's the same way they get the heat in the first place

Comment: As @JimsBond has pointed out, there are other ways for heat to be transferred. An obvious example is how you feel the heat of the sun on you, yet you clearly are not in contact with the sun. In the bigger physics picture, when you first think 'how does it lose energy', the next thought would be 'well, how would it gain energy', followed by 'how will it be in equilibrium' - then the physics starts coming out.

Comment: @JimsBond, A rigid body can not lose heat through convection.  Convection is a mechanism by which heat _flows_ in a fluid environment.  If you plonk a hot rock into a tub of cold still water, convection will distribute the heat throughout the tub, but convection is not how the heat gets from rock to water:  That bit is entirely due to conduction and radiation.

Comment: @jameslarge I know, but conventionally, all 3 are taught together. I figured I wouldn't mess with traditional pedantics

Comment: @JimsBond, Sorry, I guess I stuck my foot in it there:  Obviously, if you observe how the temperature of a hot-rock-in-cold-water changes with time, you can not explain your observations without talking about convection in the water.  Now, if we were to plonk a hot planet into a tub of cold vacuum...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Physical things (solid, liquid, gas, plasma) both absorb and emit energy in the form of electromagnetic radiation of a wide range of frequencies. How fast they radiate and the strongest frequencies of radiation depend on the absolute temperature. How fast they absorb depends on the temperatures of objects around them. Therefore, the net intensity (energy per time per surface area) transfer will depend on the temperature differences; this is NOT a linear function. No other medium needs to be surrounding the object other than space.

Some things are more efficient than others at absorbing and emitting energy.The most efficient objects are called ``blackbodies.''  Outer space is a pretty good blackbody, and its temperature is about 2.7K.  Our sun is a moderately good blackbody with a surface temperature of about 5800K.  As a result, the sun is a net energy radiator and space is a net absorber. The rate of total radiation intensity is given by Stefan's Law (determined, first, experimentally, and then affirmed theoretically by Planck): $$ I = \sigma T^4$$ where $\sigma$ is the Stefan-Boltzmann constant (a proportionality factor to make the units work right) and $T$ is the absolute temperature.

Because not everything is a blackbody (and hence, a less efficient radiator or absorber), Stefan's law applied to these less efficient things (like planets, cars and clothes) takes an extra factor:
$$I = \epsilon\sigma T^4,$$
where $\epsilon (\le 1)$ is called the emissivity and tells us the relative efficiency of a body in emitting or absorbing EM radiation (averaged over the entire spectrum).  That partially why different color objects heat or cool faster than each other.

As an example, let's consider sunspots.  They look very dark on the sun's surface. Their temperature is about 4000 K, and they would glow as brightly as almost any light bulb in your house. But the main surface of the sun is 5800 K, and glows with an intensity ratio of $$\frac{I_{surf}}{I_{spot}}=\left(\frac{5800}{4000} \right)^4 = 4.4$$, 4.4 times the intensity with a slightly more yellow peak wavelength than the spot.

The bottom line: anything with a temperature above absolute zero is continually emitting energy. It is also absorbing energy from its surroundings. This process does not require any material to ``conduct'' the energy.

Comment: Probably good idea (since we are talking about planets which are not really black bodies) to include emissivity: $I = \epsilon \sigma T^4$.

Comment: @Floris. good suggestion. Done.